# dot operaton in multiple functions calling

Tags: javascript

I was playing with Javascript and there is this one with thing which is puzzling me..

Suppose we have two functions

```
function A (argA) {
 //Do Something with argA
 return somehingFromA
}

function B (argB) {
  //Do somwthing with argB
  return somethingFromB
}
```

if we want to pass return of A to B, we would probably do this B(A(arg))

this should give return of function A to B to process?

Now, when we do something like this

```
arr.split(' ').join('-')
```

we are also pasing the return from `split` to `join`?

I know they both aren't equal, can someone tell me what I am thinking wrong?

Comment: You don't pass the result from `split` to `join`. If you call `split` on a string, it returns an Array, and an Array has a `join` function so you can call `join` on the result of `split`.

Comment: "*we are also pasing the return from `split` to `join`?*" no, it's calling `join` on the result of `split`. In once the first case you only have functions that take input and return output, in the other it's running a method on an object that is the result of a method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do see why you're confused, it *is* slightly subtle.

When you do `B(A(arg))`, you're passing `A`'s *return value* into `B`. `B` sees that value as its parameter `argB`.

When you do `arr.split(' ').join('-')` you're *using* `split`'s return value (an array) by calling a method on it, instead of passing the return value into `join` as an argument. `join` doesn't see the array as a parameter at all. (It does see it as `this`, because in the normal case when you do `obj.method()`, `this` within the call to `method` has the same value `obj` had. Which is what makes this slightly subtle.)

Answer (score 1):

For. Split(), It returns array.
For join syntax is "array you want to join". Join(separator).

As array extend function join you are using this way.

Some functions need parameter but some datatype extend function to apply some operations.

I hope that clears your doubt

Answer (score 0):

Methods are being applied to some objects. In your example .split() returns an array. join() is applied to that new array.